# Retrieve values from 3 related tables in a specific format in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have created a table for the following structure.
Section 1 
    sub section (1)
    sub section (2)
      sub sub section (a)
      sub sub section (b)
    sub section (3)

Each of the Section,sub section and sub sub section may or may not have descriptions.
I have created 3 tables.

Each table contains the following fields.

```
**Section table** - 
Sectionid(pk),Section name,Section description

**Sub Section table** - 
subsection id(pk),Section id(fk),sub section name, sub section description

**SUb Sub section table** -
sub sub section id(pk),subsection id(fk),Sectionid(fk),Sub section id(fk),description
```

Is this a right table structure.?

How can i retrieve the section descriptions from the all the 3 tables in the order mentioned above using mysql.

Please help me....

Thanks in advance

Comment: in SUb Sub section table Sectionid may not required. Please check it

Comment: Ok.I will look into it.Any reviews other than that.?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your database schema,you need to use `JOIN` operation,Try this:

```
SELECT s.description,ss.sub section description,sss.description from Section s
LEFT JOIN Sub Section ss ON s.Sectionid = ss.Sectionid
LEFT JOIN sub sub section sss ON sst.Sectionid = sss.subsection id
```

OR you can simply  use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT description from Section 
UNION ALL
SELECT sub section description from Sub Section
UNION ALL
SELECT description from sub sub section
```